# How to get unique values in multiple left join

Tags: sql-server, filter, unique-values

I have the following code I have to join 3 tables but Dest.Code has has repeated values. How can I get unique values for Dest.Code?

I have tried DISTINCT but doesn't work.

```
SELECT
   Dest.Code 
  ,City.CityName  
  ,Country.Id
FROM base.Dest
   Left join base.City
   On base.Dest.CityId = base.City.Id
   Left join base.Country 
   On base.City.CountryId = base.Country.Id
```

This is the result: But ASA appears twice. I need it only once doesn't matter which one.

```
Code    CityName    Id          
ASA     Ardmore     1E-599-4E   
ASA     Miami       8B-203-4D   
WBG     Rome        9S-893-2E   
BMU     Leon        2B-103-8E
```

Comment: Simpify your problem. (Remove some columns not needed to illustrate the issue.) Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Take a look at [mcve] before you start!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  *Which* values do you want when there are duplicates?

Comment: I have added the results. I use SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your query inside a CTE with a new column that you will use to filter the results.
This new column is produced with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function partitioned by Dest.Code:

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT Dest.Code, City.CityName, Country.Id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dest.Code ORDER BY City.CityName, Country.Id) AS rn   
  FROM Dest
  LEFT JOIN City ON Dest.CityId = City.Id
  LEFT JOIN Country ON City.CountryId = Country.Id
)
SELECT Code, CityName, Id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Hei, thanks for your answer. I tried it and got this error: The multi-part identifier "Dest.Code" could not be bound.

Comment: Try my edited answer.I removed `base.` from the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   Dest.Code 
  ,Dest.DestName 
  ,Dest.Code + ' ' + Dest.DestName as Destination
  ,Dest.Latitude
  ,Dest.Longitude
  ,Dest.CityId
  ,City.InternCityName 
  ,City.CityName 
  ,Country.CountryNameInt 
  ,Country.CountryName 
  ,Case 
     when Country.CountryName = 'Country' 
     then 'Local' 
     else 'Exterior' 
     end 
FROM DataBase.Destinations as Dest
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT Code,CityId FROM  DataBase.Destinations AS dest1 
)dest2

ON dest.CityId=dest2.CityId

Left join DataBase.Cities City
On Dest.CityId = City.Id

Left join DataBase.Countries Country
On City.CountryId = Country.Id
```

> Note:- Sub Query is using for distinct value and inner join for common
>   value only...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it make sense however I am using SQL server and it does't allow me to use DISTINCT ON, should it?

Comment: i'm not getting ...what are you trying to say..?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**. It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT Code, CityId FROM ...` to make code clearer!

Comment: OK. But when I run the code i get an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Comment: I have edited my answer ...this will work for you....definitely.. by mistake i have added this line ON dest1.CityId=Dest.CityId this line...

Comment: ON after SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: The code works. But doesn't give the desired result. I have edited the original post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Left join will always pick all value of left table...so your might be wrong  O/ P just because this...i'm not totally assure??

Comment: This code will not eliminate the duplicates that are created from left joins and will not answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of this as a creative alternative to CTE or anything using row numbers, but I have no idea on performance:

```
SELECT
   Dest.Code 
  ,max(City.CityName + ' ### ' + Country.Id)
FROM base.Dest
   Left join base.City
   On base.Dest.CityId = base.City.Id
   Left join base.Country 
   On base.City.CountryId = base.Country.Id
group by dest.code
```

This has the problem of presenting CityName and Country.Id as a single output column.  This may be acceptable -- or you can use patindex, left, and substring to split it back out:

```
SELECT
   Dest.Code 
  ,left(max(City.CityName + ' ### ' + Country.Id),patindex('% ### %',max(City.CityName + ' ### ' + Country.Id))) CityName
  ,substring(max(City.CityName + ' ### ' + Country.Id),patindex('% ### %',max(City.CityName + ' ### ' + Country.Id)) + 5,len(max(City.CityName + ' ### ' + Country.Id))) Id
FROM base.Dest
   Left join base.City
   On base.Dest.CityId = base.City.Id
   Left join base.Country 
   On base.City.CountryId = base.Country.Id
group by dest.code
```

It can get a little messy/difficult to understand.  Additionally, the (arbitrary) string added between CityName and Country.Id MUST BE KNOWN TO NOT EXIST IN CITYNAME.
Finally, the code I present does not properly account for any null values.  I would replace every instance of City.CityName and Country.Id with isnull(City.CityName,'') and isnull(Country.Id,'').